# Unable to print using Rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to access `R` from `python` using `rpy2`, both of them present on the same environment in conda.
When I try to print something from `R` using `rpy2`, it gives a strange error.

This is a MWE.

```
import os

os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/home/userxxx/anaconda3/envs/env_name/lib/R/'

import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

base = importr('base')
print(base._libPaths())
```

This gives the following error - `R[write to console]: Error in print.default(object, useS4 = FALSE) : invalid printing width`

The detailed error is as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9176a47398e9> in <module>
     11 
     12 base = importr('base')
---> 13 print(base._libPaths())

~/anaconda3/envs/env_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py in __str__(self)
     98               .callbacks.obj_in_module(rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks,
     99                                        'consolewrite_print', s.append)):
--> 100             self.__show(self)
    101         s = str.join('', s)
    102         return s

~/anaconda3/envs/env_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/conversion.py in _(*args, **kwargs)
     42 def _cdata_res_to_rinterface(function):
     43     def _(*args, **kwargs):
---> 44         cdata = function(*args, **kwargs)
     45         # TODO: test cdata is of the expected CType
     46         return _cdata_to_rinterface(cdata)

~/anaconda3/envs/env_name/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    622                     error_occured))
    623             if error_occured[0]:
--> 624                 raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
    625         return res
    626 

RRuntimeError: Error in print.default(object, useS4 = FALSE) : invalid printing width
```

I have `rpy2 version: 3.3.6`, `Python version: 3.9.4` and `R version : 3.6.1` .  Can you please help with this error. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot reproduce using rpy2 version 3.4.3 and R 4.0.

Comment: @krassowski: I updated to rpy2 3.4.4 and it solved the problem. Thank you!